# Selenium webdriver in python - Unable to get browser

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import time

url_results=[]
driver_ie = webdriver.Ie('C:\\Users\\aviv\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer')

with open ('C:\\Users\\aviv\\Desktop\\urlspart.txt','r') as d:
    urls= d.read().splitlines()

    for i,url in enumerate(urls):

        try:
            print "URL: " + url
            driver_ie.get(url)
            time.sleep(7)
            current_url_ie = driver_ie.current_url
            redirect_ie='No'
            if current_url_ie == 'https://www.aviv.com':
                redirect_ie ='Yes'

        except Exception,e:
            redirect_ie = 'error'
            print e, Exception  



        writer.writerow([i,url,redirect_ie])
ofile.close()
```

This code throw exception with message: "Unable to get browser".

I have already changed Internet Options --> Security and signed the "Enable protected mode",
But the error still exists.

Anyone solution ?

Comment: why are you initializing `driver_ie` twice ??

Comment: I edited it , this is not the issue.

Comment: Can you paste the full error stack trace for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates.

For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0

Download the registry file from http://heliumhq.com/docs/internet_explorer.

See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver for this and more necessary IE configuration steps.

Also refer :

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6511

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, but i have tried it too and error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

May be because of missing .exe at end of the driver path. please add .exe as given below. it may be works for you.

```
driver_ie = webdriver.Ie('C:\\Users\\aviv\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe')
```